# Как масштабировать картинку и рисовать на ней в xamarin.forms

Tags: изображения, xamarin, масштабирование, обработка-изображений

Собственно приложение забирает с сервера картинку. Она довольно большая (схема помещения).
Как в приложении на форме сделать чтобы она масштабировалась, плюс чтобы можно было делать отметки простой линией.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используем Xamarin.Controls.SignaturePad.Forms

XAML:

```
 <helpers:PinchToZoomContainer Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" IsClippedToBounds="True" x:Name="PinchPanContainer">
                <forms:SignaturePadView StrokeColor="Black" 
                                        BackgroundColor="White" 
                                        x:Name="SpImageEditor" 
                                        IsClippedToBounds="True"
                                        SignatureLineColor="White"
                                        CaptionText=" "
                                        />
            </helpers:PinchToZoomContainer>
```

.CS

```
public class PinchToZoomContainer : ContentView
{
    double currentScale = 1;
    double startScale = 1;
    double xOffset = 0;
    double yOffset = 0;
    double x, y, startX, startY;

    public PinchToZoomContainer ()
    {
        var pinchGesture = new PinchGestureRecognizer ();
        pinchGesture.PinchUpdated += OnPinchUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add (pinchGesture);

        var panGesture = new PanGestureRecognizer();
        panGesture.PanUpdated += OnPanUpdated;
        GestureRecognizers.Add(panGesture);
    }

    void OnPanUpdated(object sender, PanUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {


        switch (e.StatusType)
        {
            case GestureStatus.Started:
                startX = e.TotalX;
                startY = e.TotalY;
                Content.AnchorX = 0;
                Content.AnchorY = 0;
                break;

            case GestureStatus.Running:
                var maxTranslationX = Content.Scale * Content.Width - Content.Width;
                Content.TranslationX = Math.Min(0, Math.Max(-maxTranslationX, xOffset + e.TotalX - startX));

                var maxTranslationY = Content.Scale * Content.Height - Content.Height;
                Content.TranslationY = Math.Min(0, Math.Max(-maxTranslationY, yOffset + e.TotalY - startY));
                break;

            case GestureStatus.Completed:
                xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
                yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
                break;
        }

    }

    void OnPinchUpdated (object sender, PinchGestureUpdatedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Started) {
            // Store the current scale factor applied to the wrapped user interface element,
            // and zero the components for the center point of the translate transform.
            startScale = Content.Scale;
            Content.AnchorX = 0;
            Content.AnchorY = 0;
        }
        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Running) {
            // Calculate the scale factor to be applied.
            currentScale += (e.Scale - 1) * startScale;
            currentScale = Math.Max (1, currentScale);

            // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
            // so get the X pixel coordinate.
            double renderedX = Content.X + xOffset;
            double deltaX = renderedX / Width;
            double deltaWidth = Width / (Content.Width * startScale);
            double originX = (e.ScaleOrigin.X - deltaX) * deltaWidth;

            // The ScaleOrigin is in relative coordinates to the wrapped user interface element,
            // so get the Y pixel coordinate.
            double renderedY = Content.Y + yOffset;
            double deltaY = renderedY / Height;
            double deltaHeight = Height / (Content.Height * startScale);
            double originY = (e.ScaleOrigin.Y - deltaY) * deltaHeight;

            // Calculate the transformed element pixel coordinates.
            double targetX = xOffset - (originX * Content.Width) * (currentScale - startScale);
            double targetY = yOffset - (originY * Content.Height) * (currentScale - startScale);

            // Apply translation based on the change in origin.
            Content.TranslationX = targetX.Clamp (-Content.Width * (currentScale - 1), 0);
            Content.TranslationY = targetY.Clamp (-Content.Height * (currentScale - 1), 0);

            // Apply scale factor
            Content.Scale = currentScale;
        }
        if (e.Status == GestureStatus.Completed) {
            // Store the translation delta's of the wrapped user interface element.
            xOffset = Content.TranslationX;
            yOffset = Content.TranslationY;
        }
    }
}
```